Solving $[\partial_x^3 + (ik)^3 - u(x)]w(x) = 0$
Let us consider the operators
$$
\begin{align*}
L_0 &= \partial_x^3 - (ik)^3 + u(x) \\
L_1 &= \partial_x^3 + (ik)^3 - u(x)
\end{align*}
$$
I wish prove that a solution $w(x) : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ for $L_1 w = 0$ can be expressed as
$$
\begin{equation}
w(x) = \psi(x,k) \frac{\partial \phi(x, k)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial \psi(x,k)}{\partial x} \phi(x, k)
\end{equation}
$$
where $\psi(x, k)$ and $\phi(x, k)$ are both solutions to $L_0 \psi = 0$.
If we define an inner product as
$$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)^* g(x) dx$$
The support of $w(x)$ would restrict the domain of integration to $[0, \infty)$. Assuming that the boundary conditions are such that we are allowed to integrate by parts, take $v(x)$ to be any sufficiently nice function
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle v, L_1 w \rangle &= \langle v(x), [\partial_x^3 - ik^3 - u(x)] w(x)\rangle \\
&= \langle [-\partial_x^3 + ik^3 -u(x)] v(x), w(x)\rangle \\
&= \langle [-L_0 + 2ik^3] v(x), w(x)\rangle
\end{align*}
$$
Would I be correct in guessing that $L_1^{\dagger} = -L_0 + 2ik^3$? Could this play a role in proving that $w(x)$ takes the above form? I guess I could always try to manually evaluate the operators, but I don't feel that would be particularly elucidating.
